# Error while changing API level from 23 to 22

Tags: android, sdk, android-min-sdk

I want to change the minimum SDK version in Android Studio from API 23 to API 22 as HttpClient is not supported in API 23.I have tried changing it in build.gradle(Module:app) ie I have changed the compileSdkVersion from 23 to 22 and targetSdkVersion from 23 to 22.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.gcmgreetingapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile project(':android-query-full.0.26.7')
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
}
```

Then, sync and rebuild the project. But i got the following error in gradle console

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\nischal.manandhar\\AndroidStudioProjects\\GCMGreetingApp\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.0.0\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\nischal.manandhar\\AndroidStudioProjects\\GCMGreetingApp\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.0.0\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}


FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The error is in the file v23\values-v23.xml

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated

Comment: Ya but it was working in Api level 22 and now its not working in 23!!

Comment: Try using HttpUrlConnection - got more support and works on all API versions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I got Apache HTTP client working even in API 23 using org.apache.http.legacy.jar library. Following configuration worked.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.gcmgreetingapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile project(':android-query-full.0.26.7')
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

I manually copied **org.apache.http.legacy.jar** from **Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional** folder to app/libs in my project,then added

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

inside android{...} tag.

Comment: Your question was to switch your compileSdkVersion from 23 to 22 !! And you have answered for how to make HttpClient work for target api 23 ?!!

Answer (score 2):

Change it in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Cheers

Comment: this is the worse answer do not listen to this

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

To

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`

Do this alongwith `compileSdkVersion` `targetSdkVersion` set to `22`

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "au.com.websutra.gcmgreetingapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile project(':android-query-full.0.26.7')
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
}
```

Comment: @Nischal Move ahead . Vote up if helped .

Answer (score 2):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "au.com.websutra.gcmgreetingapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile project(':android-query-full.0.26.7')
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
}
```

**Note: Change folder name from "values-v23" to "values-v22"**

Answer (score 1):

The error arise because you've used `sdk version 23` and `build tools 22.0.1`.
Update the build tools to the latest (download them also). Here's the configuration:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.gcmgreetingapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
  compile project(':android-query-full.0.26.7')
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
}
```

**UPDATE:** : Until `async-http` library is updated, you can use this:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```